# Android app only shows froyo interface

Tags: java, android, xml

Luckily I had just backed up all of my progress and my app's source code was not ruined. However, if someone could explain exactly what happened so I could never do it again, it would be appreciated. 
I translated my strings.xml file and put the copy in a values-es folder. There was an error in the xml file, so suddenly every line of java that referenced the R class was an error. I fixed the xml error and cleaned all projects. Problem solved.
Except now, no matter which version of android the phone was running, the app appeared as if the phone were running froyo or gingerbread. This didn't work to well on my phone running 4.4.4 with no menu key and no action bar. What happened?

Comment: I think you might have changed the app base theme.

Comment: But how? When in that process could that have happened?

Comment: check you theme tag in Styles.xml file. It's there in values folder. If you removed `values-v11` and/or `values-v14` folder from `res` directory, it'll only recognise old themes that were there in `values` folder from older OS of Android.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in theme as @DroidDev said. Upload your manifest file code.

Comment: Also check the targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml to ensure that it's set to the newest API level (e.g. android:targetSdkVersion="21").